# In Apache Airflow Tool, DAG wont run due to Duplicate Entry Problem in task_instance table

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Today all day i have been getting this error in the scheduler of Airflow.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '%' fir key 'PRIMARY')")
```

Because of this the Airflow Scheduler would stop and every time i ran this had the same problem

Comment: I have found the solution to this problem. This happens if used MySQL DB as metadata store.

This problem is a bug in Apache JIRA issues : 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues/AIRFLOW-3045?filter=allopenissues

This can be fixed by altering the table and removing the extra `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Hence the fix for this is :

alter table `task_instance` change `execution_date` `execution_date` TIMESTAMP(6) not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6);

Comment: Please *never* post here images of text.  text can be copy-paste here and format as a quote or code, or readability.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to MySQL's ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and this is posted in JIRA of Airflow :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues/AIRFLOW-3045?filter=allopenissues

I fixed this by altering the table to

```
alter table `task_instance` change `execution_date` `execution_date` TIMESTAMP(6) not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6);
```

Comment: There is no column 'execution_date'